# Replace Product ID with Product Name in Laravel Collection

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel collection with the list of items in the user's cart. Below is my code for fetching that collection:

```
$items = Cart_Item::all();
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->toUser();
$items = $items->where('user_id', $user->id);
$items = $items->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return collect($item)->except(['user_id', 'ip_address', 'created_at', 'updated_at'])->toArray();
});
```

With this I get the following output:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "product_id": 1,
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Now in this I want to replace the `product_id` with my actual product name using the `product` model and also add a field named `price` using the `product_pricing` model. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the relationships setup correctly, you could do:

```
$items = $items->map(function ($item, $key) {
  $product = Product::with('price')->where('id', $item->product_id)->first();
  return [
     'id'    => $item->id,
     'product_id' => $item->product_id,
     'quantity' => $item->quantity,
     'name'  => $product->name,
     'price' => $product->price->amount,
  ];
});
```

Or the manual inner join way:

```
$product = Product::select('*')
 ->join('product_pricing as pp', 'pp.product_id', '=', 'product.id')
 ->where('product.id', $item->product_id)
 ->first();
```

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks! I mean I modified it little to suit me but the logic was perfectly the same